# Python loop through text and set numpy array index

Tags: python, numpy

Given a block of text with matrix rows and columns separated by commas and semicolons, I want to parse the text and set the indices of numpy arrays. Here is the code with the variable 'matrixText' representing the base text.

I first create the matrices and then split the text by semicolons and then by commas. I loop through the split text and set each index. However with the text ...

1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9

I get the result

7,7,7;8,8,8;9,9,9

```
temp1=matrixText.split(';')
temp2=temp1[0].split(',')
rows=len(temp1)
columns=len(temp2)
rA=np.zeros((rows, columns))
arrayText=matrixText.split(';')
rowText=range(len(arrayText))
for rowIndex, rowItem in enumerate(arrayText):
    rowText[rowIndex]=arrayText[rowIndex].split(',')
    for colIndex, colItem in enumerate(rowText[rowIndex]):
        rA[[rowIndex, colIndex]]=rowText[rowIndex][colIndex]
```

I thought that by setting each index, I would avoid any copy by reference issues.

To provide more info, in the first iteration, the 0,0 index is set to 1 and the output of that is then 1,1,1;0,0,0;0,0,0 which I can't figure out since setting one index in the numpy array sets three.

In the second iteration, the index 0-1 is set to 2 and the result is then 2,2,2;2,2,2;0,0,0

The third iteration sets 0-2 to 3 but the result is 3,3,3;2,2,2;3,3,3

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt)?

Comment: It's not coming from a file, and I really need to solve the problem as I am afraid that I may have related issues

Comment: Some redundant code... E.g., why do you have `arrayText=matrixText.split(';')`? Wouldn't `temp1` be the same as `arrayText`?

Comment: I was just trying to show that I used the size of the split to create an "empty" numpy array and then set each index. The problem is the apparent set by reference somewhere.

Comment: What is `iA` used for?

Comment: Something else. It shouldn't be there, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab-) use the `matrix` constructor plus the `A` property

```
np.matrix('1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9').A
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: UV! I really like this!

Comment: @AGNGazer Yep, the `matrix` class isn't totally useless ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
matrixText = '1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9'
temp1=matrixText.split(';')
temp2=temp1[0].split(',')
rows=len(temp1)
columns=len(temp2)
rA=np.empty((rows, columns),dtype=np.int)
for n, line in enumerate(temp1):         
    rA[n,:]=line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using a nested `list-comprehension`:**

Having defined:

```
s = "1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9"
```

we can use a nice `one-liner`:

```
np.array([[int(c) for c in r.split(",")] for r in s.split(";")])
```

which would give the following `array`:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner (+1 import):

```
from io import StringIO
rA = np.loadtxt(StringIO(matrixText.replace(';','\n')), delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here was that the dual brackets in rA[[rowIndex, colIndex]] caused every cell in the row to be set. This should be rA[rowIndex, colIndex]